# JSON-file (or XML if it it easier) into a modified XML-file in python

Tags: python, json, xml

I had to start a new question because in the previous post I forgot to mention something crucial.. I am trying to do this in python. I try to open a json-file, go through of it, modify it and then save the modified contents in XML format.

example.json

```
[{"person": "idnum1", "data": "exampledata1"}, {"person": "idnum1", "data": "exampledata2"}, {"person": "idnum2", "data": "exampledata1"}, {"person": "idnum2", "data": "exampledata2"}, {"person": "idnum2", "data": "exampledata3"}]
```

I am able to go through the json-file line be line using "for variable in dictionary" -kind of approach after I have opened the json-file with the json.load method. I am able to convert the json-structure into a xml-structure and save it as a xml-file. What I am missing is the modifying part of the code.

With that example.json my pythoncode will produce a xml-file as so:

```
<PERSON ID="idnum1">
<data>
    exampledata1
</data></PERSON><PERSON ID="idnum1">
<data>
    exampledata2
</data></PERSON><PERSON ID="idnum2">
<data>
    exampledata1
</data></PERSON><PERSON ID="idnum2">
<data>
    exampledata2
</data></PERSON><PERSON ID="idnum2">
<data>
    exampledata3
</data></PERSON>
```

But what should I do in python to modify the loaded json so that I could save it as a xml like this?

```
<PERSON ID="idnum1">
<data>
    exampledata1 exampledata2
</data></PERSON><PERSON ID="idnum2">
<data>
    exampledata1 exampledata2 exampledata3
</data></PERSON>
```

So in other words, as long as the person remains the same, the data referring to that person should be collected together into one subelement of one person element in xml, and when the person changes in the original json-file, then there should be an other element in xml for that person and it should contain all the data referring to that person in one subelement.

NOTICE! I can get the original data from the external system also in xml format in the first place, but it also should be modified with python so that the end result would remain the same as I am intending (combining one persons data into one subelement of one personelement). At the moment I can get from the json-file into a similiar xml-file which I could get out from the system in the first place.

Comment: start by uploading a VALID xml data. " ...xml like this?" is not a valid xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough python to give you a python solution, but here's an XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="json-doc('input.json')?*" 
                    group-adjacent="?person">
  <PERSON ID="{current-grouping-key()}">
    <data>{current-group()?data}</data>
  </PERSON>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

XSLT 3.0 is available to Python users via the Saxon/C product.

Comment: Thank you Michael! How would your code change if the source-file was XML and not JSON?

Comment: It would depend on the exact format of the XML. But it would then be a perfectly standard XSLT grouping stylesheet.

Comment: What should I do with that "select="json-doc..." -part of the code then if the source is xml-file instead of json-file?

Comment: You could use the doc() function, or more likely you would make the XML file the primary input to the transformation. I'm afraid this isn't the place for a beginner's tutorial on XSLT - there are plenty of good ones around (the best in book form...)

Answer (score 0):

Using ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

holder = defaultdict(list)

data = [{"person": "idnum1", "data": "exampledata1"}, {"person": "idnum1", "data": "exampledata2"},
        {"person": "idnum2", "data": "exampledata1"}, {"person": "idnum2", "data": "exampledata2"},
        {"person": "idnum2", "data": "exampledata3"}]


for entry in data:
        holder[entry['person']].append(entry['data'])

top = ET.Element('top')
for k,v in holder.items():
        person = ET.SubElement(top, 'person')
        person.attrib['id'] = k
        text = ' '.join(v)
        data = ET.SubElement(person, 'data')
        data.text = text
print(ET.tostring(top).decode())
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
   <person id="idnum1">
      <data>exampledata1 exampledata2</data>
   </person>
   <person id="idnum2">
      <data>exampledata1 exampledata2 exampledata3</data>
   </person>
</top>
```